# Int and str variables

Tags: php, string, integer

I'm a little unclear about the rule for integer and string variables in php.

If I am dealing with counters (simple integers starting with 1 and counting upwards), do I need to specify variables as integers and then convert to strings when I use or can I leave them as strings and conversions will happen automatically in php at run time?

Or are there too many specific cases that have different rules? Some thoughts would be appreciated...

Comment: PHP will automatically convert between string and numeric types. Just use numeric types and when outputting them (e.g. with `echo`) they will automatically be converted to a string.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php what you like to know is here

Comment: yes. php covert or understand integer or string automatically. You don't have to define it

Comment: Why do you think you may need to specify numeric counters as strings?

Comment: The counters are retrieved from a file using regular expressions so start off as a string - some situations require numeric comparisons/increments, others as strings, eg adding to a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` automatically  converts `valriables` when needed. you just have to be careful when you are going to compare them.

`If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.`

take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

There's no variable declaration in PHP the variable will take the type appropiate to the data you assign to it.

```
$var = 1;    //here $var is an int
$var = '1';  // now is a string
$var = true; //and now a boolean
```